# Series of Real Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_{k}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $0 \lt a_{k+1}\le a_{k}$ for all k. If $\alpha\ge2$, is it true that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(a_{k}-a_{k+1})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$ converges?

Comment: This is not true. Take $a_{k}=\frac{1}{k}$ and $\alpha=2$